# Fitrar tabla excel por fecha y hora

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una macro la cual es para filtrar una tabla adquirida de un scraping web, la macro mi filtra las fechas bien pero cuando quiero filtrar por horas tengo problemas

En que puedo estar fallando?

les dejo el codigo

```
Sub Filtrodefecha()
    Dim fechadesde As Long
    Dim fechahasta As Long
    fechadesde = Worksheets("Sismos").Range("J1")
    fechahasta = Worksheets("Sismos").Range("M1")
    With ActiveSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode = True Then .AutoFilterMode = trur
    End With
    Range("A1").AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & fechadesde, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & fechahasta, _
        visibledropdown:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: *cuando quiero filtrar por horas tengo problemas* Esto es impreciso. ¿Qué tipo de problemas? De todas formas piensa que una fecha es un valor numérico entero y una hora es un valor numérico decimal. Si en la celda solo hay horas, son valores comprendidos entre 0 y 1, con lo que tu filtro nunca mostraría nada. De todas formas edita tu pregunta, añade datos de ejemplo y especifica mejor el problema que tienes. Tu pregunta ahora mismo es demasiado abierta y es pura suerte encontrar la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

No se especifica el problema que se da, pero cuando se trata de fechas, es muy importante el formato que tienen las celdas con los datos.

Posiblemente lo que pasa es que tu columna de fecha y hora no tiene el formato adecuado, pero aun así, quizá los datos no son fechas y hora reales.

tanto las celdas de la columna de fecha y hora deben tener el mismo formato que las celdas de criterios.

Los datos deberían verse así: `12/09/2021 10:14` o así `12/09/2021 10:15 a. m.`

Los formatos correspondientes son estos `dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm` y `dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm AM/PM`

Si solo son horas, el formato debe ser este: `hh:mm` o este otro `hh:mm AM/PM`

Si los datos se pegaron desde otra fuente, es posible que se hayan pegado como texto, si aplicas el formato adecuado, posiblemente aun permanecerán como texto, se puede solucionar seleccionando la celda y presionando la tecla de función F2 y luego enter, pero eso es un problema si hay muchos registros.

Lo anterior se puede automatizar con la siguiente macro.

```
Sub SimulaF2Enter()
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        SendKeys "{F2}", True
        SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

No ejecutes la macro desde el editor VBA, ve a la hoja que tiene los datos, selecciona la primera celda a procesar con el F2 Enter, presiona la tecla de función F8, selecciona la macro SimulaF2Enter y Ejecutar.

No hagas nada mientras se ejecuta el proceso.